# Comet Help on linux hosting

Tags: php, ajax, apache, comet

I have a shared linux hosting. Apache is running on it. My site is built in php. I have a chat application which uses ajax long polling. I want to turn it to comet chat. I do not have much knowledge about server things. Please help me step by step suggestion. It will be a great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Long Polling is a type of Comet.

But either your chat application isn't well used or your provider will kick you in a few days. A chat using Long Polling may only have as many participants as there are PHP processes. Each participant - each connection - takes up a PHP process. I don't think that your provider is okay that your application takes 100 processes at a time.

Comment: My situation is when a ajax request is made and it waits on the server, I have few more ajax requests to make,like online users etc. All holds up till the first request is completed.